# SQL - CASE statement: "Inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got CHAR"

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have written an CASE statement (as a apart of a longer query) that looks for invoices in a table, if it finds an invoice, it returns the last invoice date, otherwise a string "No Invoices".

I understand that data types should be consistent, this is why I have converted the date to string, but this way the date can't be sorted in Excel as it is exported as a string.

How can I make this work and keep the date in the correct date format without having to convert it to a string?

Thank you!

```
case when exists (select * from AP_INVOICES_ALL i where i.VENDOR_SITE_ID = s.VENDOR_SITE_ID)
     then (select to_char(max(i.INVOICE_DATE)) from AP_INVOICES_ALL i where i.VENDOR_SITE_ID=s.VENDOR_SITE_ID)  
     else 'No invoices'
end as "AP Last Invoice Date"
```

Comment: Tag our question with the database you are using.

Comment: `to-char` should be `to_char`.

Comment: @MT0 Thank you. Well spotted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use `NULL` to represent the lack of invoice date.  But if you need to use a string, one option is to use a date in a sortable format:

```
to_char(max(i.INVOICE_DATE), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It does show the date in the correct format, but when I export to Excel, Excel doesn't recognise it as a date which means I can't use filter on that column.

Comment: @Adrian . . . That is odd.  Excel has always recognized YYYY-MM-DD columns for me.  I can think of two possibilities.  Perhaps the initial values are all strings, so Excel does not recognize them.  Or perhaps you have internationalization settings set in a way that the dates are not valid.  For the first, I would suggest using `NULL`.

Comment: Hi. I have used NULL and removed to_char and it works great now. Thank you very much! I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your `case` you can use [`coalesce`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp):

```
coalesce(to_char(max(i.INVOICE_DATE), 'YYYY-MM-DD'),'No invoices') as "AP Last Invoice Date"
```

When the first argument returns null, it takes the next.

Comment: Thank you. The issue I am having is that once the data is exported into Excel, even though the date is in correct format, Excel does not see it as a date, hence makes it impossible to use the dates from that column in the analysis.